# Rotate line over a circle - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I rotate the line 360 degrees (every 20 degrees) over the circle and find the intersecting coordinates?

```
r = 1;
xc = 5;
yc = 5;

theta = linspace(0,2*pi);
x = r*cos(theta) + xc;
y = r*sin(theta) + yc;
plot(x,y)
axis equal
hold on

plot([xc xc-2],[yc yc])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "find the intersecting" ?

Comment: The coordinates that the line intersect with the circle perimeter.

Comment: But this can be computed simply and explicitly. `xs = xc + cos(coase_theta)`. It's not *find*.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean with coase_theta? How can I rotate the line [xc xc-2],[yc yc] every 20 degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to construct a coarse linspace:

```
how_many_point = 360 / 20
coarse_theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, how_many_point + 1)
xs = xc + cos(coarse_theta)
ys = yc + sin(coarse_theta)

for i = 1:how_many_point
plot([xs(i) xc], [ys(i) yc]); hold on
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can increase the lines plots as increase the R?

Comment: What is R? You want to increase the length of lines or the number of lines?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. R is the radius and I wish to increase the line lengths.

Comment: Replace xs = xc + cos(coarse_theta) by xs = xc + R*cos(coarse_theta). Do the same thing for ys.